# Heat sink Design

Tags: mechanical-engineering, heat-transfer

I have a problem where there is an 80 Watt thermal load that needs to be cooled to maintain 80 Celsius. The base of the heat sink is 5" x 7" and is oriented vertically with cooling via natural convection. I am to provide the temperature differential of the heat sink vs. the thermal load based on the fin density.

- Selected material: Aluminum 1050
- Fin shape: Rectangle

To solve I found the film temperature, which helped me find the Beta (coefficient of volume expansion). I could then find the Rayleigh number, which in turn allowed me to find the optimal spacing between the fins. I selected a various amount of fin thicknesses and solved for the number of fins required based on its thickness. I then found the heat transfer coefficient. At this point I have everything required to solve the equation:

$$Q = h(2 \cdot n_{fins} \cdot Length \cdot Height) \times (T_s-T_a)$$

I am at a position where I don't know what to do. I don't understand what I am supposed to be comparing. I can find the temperature differential based on the information I found, but I don't know how the thermal load changes based on fin density.

Any help in steering me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I have to imagine that this problem requires an analysis that uses [a fin efficiency](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/fin-efficiency) expression $\dot{q} = h(A_o + N_{fins} A_f \eta_f)\Delta T$.